# How To Call Our Own Build withNavigation In React Native 6

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Help,

Firstly, did React Native 6 or 5 have withNavigation ? I cannot find it in the documentation in React Native website.

So, I found some thread that we can build our own withNavigation like this :

**withNavigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'; // not sure package name


export const withNavigation = (Component) => {
  return (props) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return <Component navigation={navigation} {...props} />;
  };
};
```

But I don't know how to call or use the own build withNavigation.

This is my source code :

**ResultList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import ResultsDetail from './ResultsDetail';
import { withNavigation } from '../helper/withNavigation';

const ResultList = ({ title, results }) => {
    console.log(withNavigation.component);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}> 
            <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>            
            <FlatList
                horizontal={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                data={results}
                keyExtractor={(results) => results.id}
                renderItem={({item}) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => withNavigation('ResultShowScreen')}>
                            <ResultsDetail results={item} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                }}

            />
        </View>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({    
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginLeft: 15,
        marginBottom: 5,

    },
    container: {
        marginBottom: 10
    }
});

export default ResultList;
```

In here :

*console.log(withNavigation.component)*

it show : undefined

How to get the navigation props with our own withNavigation ?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your helper function, `withNavigation`, is a [Higher-Order Component (HoC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) you have to wrap your component with it in order to be able to use it:

```
const ResultList = ({ title, results, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      <FlatList
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={results}
        keyExtractor={(results) => results.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            // Now you can use the navigation prop inside of your component
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyRoute')}>
              <ResultsDetail results={item} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

// withNavigation adds the navigation property to your ResultList component's properties
export default withNavigation(ResultList);
```

I think the reason why you can't find `withNavigation` inside of React Navigation 5 or 6 anymore is because they suggest you to use their built-in hooks instead. I am not sure why do you need to use a custom made `HoC` when you could just use the `useNavigation` hook. If you don't have a [specific reason](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/do-react-hooks-replace-higher-order-components-hocs-7ae4a08b7b58) to use your custom `HoC`, the built-in hooks could simplify your code:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const ResultList = ({ title, results }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      <FlatList
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={results}
        keyExtractor={(results) => results.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            // You can use the navigation property inside of your component
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyRoute')}>
              <ResultsDetail results={item} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ResultList;
```

Comment: Thank You @Kapobajza, It is clear now. I will try it first and then mark as the final answer.

Comment: @DennisLiu okay

Answer (score 0):

As per the upgrading documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/upgrading-from-4.x/#higher-order-components)

> React Navigation 4.x included higher order components such as
> withNavigation and withNavigationFocus. Now they live in the compat
> package.

The documentation says that in order to upgrade from React Navigation 4 to 5:
`withNavigation` HOC is moved to another package `@react-navigation/compat`

So, in order to use that you have to import that package first:

```
import { withNavigation } from '@react-navigation/compat';
```